# count variable length in Spotfire

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I have a boolean/logic variable (values 0, 1) and I need to know dataset size in order to do some math (like calculating percentages)

For example, if my dataset has 250 rows, I want to do something similar to this:

```
Count([variable]) / 250
```

The point is that i dont know dataset's length (it will use different datasets each time). Thats why I need a function similar to R length(data$variable) who gives me the amount of rows in the variable.

Ive tried without success different count() combinations. Anyone knows a length() function or similar to know the amount of rows?

Comment: `count()` should return the number of rows in the current filtering. are you trying to show the number of total rows sans filters?

Comment: Yes, im trying to show the total count() without filters. So if the column has 250rows, I want to get count()=250 regardles of filters.

Comment: are you evaluating in a calculated column or axis expression or somewhere else?

Comment: Im evaluating it for a label scale in a bar char. I have X axis splitted in 5% ranges, And my Y axis has another variable with this expression: Count([var]) / (2243936 / 20). Where "2243936" is the total number of rows.
The point is that I dont know how to automatically get that "2243936"

Comment: gotcha. I was thinking you could use the Advanced Settings (**Settings** button next to the axis' **Columns** field in the properties dialog) to toggle between *Current filtering* and *All data* but I don't think it'll work in a bar chart... how do you feel about using a document property that contains the number of rows?

Comment: I guess I should be more specific: in your workflow when using the analysis, is there some other action that the user takes that can be tied to a script that updates a document property with the number of rows?

Comment: What determines what dataset is used

Comment: @scsimon since he's evaluating on the axis I think it'd just be the data table assigned to the viz (unless Akiru is using cross-table expressions like some kind of mad cowboy :)

Comment: I see now @niko. Document property should do the trick, no?

Comment: should do; but it'll require some user intervention unless access is through a link into web player or Akriu feels like playing with JS timers

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I believe `Count(RowId())` would work.

Comment: `Count()`, `Count(RowId())`, and `Count([var])` (assuming there are not empty values) will all return the same number. from the docs for `Count()`: "Calculates the number of non-empty values in the argument column, or, if no argument is specified, the total number of rows."

Comment: I see, you're right. Thanks for the input. I'm anxious to read the answer that solves @akiru's problem.